# Oracle REGEXPR_SUBSTR

Tags: regex, oracle, expression, substr

I am hoping someone can give me a good way to do this:

I have a string:

```
annual_sales:79139,annual_ind:A,q4_sales:22543,q4_ind:A,q3_sales:19153,q3_ind:A,q2_sales:19289,q2_ind:A,q1_sales:18155,q1_ind:A
```

The string will always have the same parts.  Always 10 sections separated by commas.  Each each 2 pair go together.  So, you see this:

```
annual_sales:79139
annual_ind:A

q4_sales:22543
q4_ind:A

q3_sales:19153
q3_ind:A

q2_sales:19289
q2_ind:A

q1_sales:18155
q1_ind:A
```

I need both pairs to do the necessary processing.

I need both `annual_sales:79139` and `annual_ind:A` to process that.

I need both `q4_sales:22543` and `q4_ind:A` to process that, and so on

I'm hoping somehow, maybe with a loop and REGEXPR_SUBSTR to get the pairs.  Maybe loop 5 times, get the pairs I need each time?

I can do this very clumsy with SUBSTR & INSTR, but hoping the REGEXPR can be a bit more clean.

So, extract the first 2 pairs, do what I need.  Get the second 2 pairs, do what is needed, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using something like:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(SALES_STRING, '(annual_sales:)([^,]+)',1,1,NULL,2) AS ANNUAL_SALES,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(SALES_STRING, '(annual_ind:)([^,]+)',1,1,NULL,2) AS ANNUAL_IND,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(SALES_STRING, '(q1_sales:)([^,]+)',1,1,NULL,2) AS Q1_SALES,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(SALES_STRING, '(q1_ind:)([^,]+)',1,1,NULL,2) AS Q1_IND,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(SALES_STRING, '(q2_sales:)([^,]+)',1,1,NULL,2) AS Q2_SALES,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(SALES_STRING, '(q2_ind:)([^,]+)',1,1,NULL,2) AS Q2_IND,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(SALES_STRING, '(q3_sales:)([^,]+)',1,1,NULL,2) AS Q3_SALES,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(SALES_STRING, '(q3_ind:)([^,]+)',1,1,NULL,2) AS Q3_IND,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(SALES_STRING, '(q4_sales:)([^,]+)',1,1,NULL,2) AS Q4_SALES,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(SALES_STRING, '(q4_ind:)([^,]+)',1,1,NULL,2) AS Q4_IND
  FROM YOUR_TABLE
```

where `YOUR_TABLE.SALES_STRING` is the table and column which contains the string. This will produce a result similar to:

```
ANNUAL_SALES ANNUAL_IND Q1_SALES Q1_IND Q2_SALES Q2_IND Q3_SALES Q3_IND Q4_SALES  Q4_IND
79139        A          18155    A      19289    A      19153    A      22543     A
```

[dbfiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=3b5608d1dc3957ef833b8ed66b905cde)

Best of luck.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a regex solution which doesn't require the hardcoding of the labels. The subquery splits the string on every second comma, then the main query splits the resultant pair into two columns.

```
with t23 as  (
  select  'annual_sales:79139,annual_ind:A,q4_sales:22543,q4_ind:A,q3_sales:19153,q3_ind:A,q2_sales:19289,q2_ind:A,q1_sales:18155,q1_ind:A' str
  from dual
 )
  , prs as (
  select regexp_substr(str, '([^,]+,[^,]+)', 1, level) as pr
  from t23
  connect by level <= 5 
  )
select substr(pr, 1, instr(pr, ',')-1) as sales
       , substr(pr, instr(pr, ',')+1) as ind
from prs
order by 1
;
```

The output looks like this:

```
SALES               IND
------------------  -----------
annual_sales:79139  annual_ind:A
q1_sales:18155      q1_ind:A
q2_sales:19289      q2_ind:A
q3_sales:19153      q3_ind:A
q4_sales:22543      q4_ind:A
```

If you want to have something which is ready for processing we can get fancier:

```
with t23 as  (
  select  'annual_sales:79139,annual_ind:A,q4_sales:22543,q4_ind:A,q3_sales:19153,q3_ind:A,q2_sales:19289,q2_ind:A,q1_sales:18155,q1_ind:A' str
  from dual
 )
  , prs as (
  select regexp_substr(str, '([^,]+,[^,]+)', 1, level) as pr
  from t23
  connect by level <= 5 
  )
select substr(pr, 1, instr(pr, '_')-1) as label
       , ltrim(regexp_substr(pr, ':([0-9]+)'), ':') as sales
       , substr(pr, -1, 1) as ind
from prs
order by 1
;
```

Gives output:

```
LABEL   SALES  IND
------  -----  ---
annual  79139  A
q1      18155  A
q2      19289  A
q3      19153  A
q4      22543  A
```

---

Incidentally, this question illustrates a bugbear of mine. This question is only necessary because the input string is poorly formatted. There's an implicit structure in the content which isn't expressed in the structure of the string. It's 2018, why are we still passing data around like this? We have had XML for decades, JSON since 2001. There's no excuse.

I agree this is more verbose, but how much easier to process, how much more robust:

```
"report": {
    "annual" : {
       "sales" : 79139
       , "ind" : A
    }
    , "q1" : {
       "sales" : 18155
       , "ind" : A
    }
    , "q2" : {
       "sales" : 19289
       , "ind" : A
    }
    , "q3" : {
       "sales" : 19153
       , "ind" : A
    }
    , "q4" : {
       "sales" : 22543
       , "ind" : A
    }
}
```

Buy you don't have to go the full JSON. Even this would be a marked improvement:

```
[annual_sales:79139,annual_ind:A],[q4_sales:22543,q4_ind:A],[q3_sales:19153,q3_ind:A],[q2_sales:19289,q2_ind:A],[q1_sales:18155,q1_ind:A]
```

At least we have a reliable notation for related pairs of values.